# For JSONArray parsing: TRY inside LOOP or LOOP inside TRY?

Tags: java, json

I've a JSONArray. I want to parse it into JSONObject. So Loop and try-catch are must.
Silly question is: Should I use FOR loop inside the TRY or reverse? Is it really matter or both are same?
Please tell me the best practice (if both are not same).

#### FOR loop inside the TRY:

```
try {
        for(i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //do something
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

#### TRY inside the Loop

```
for(i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //do something
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Which one is preferable?

Comment: It might help if you provide a tag for the language you are using?

Comment: Java language tag added.

Comment: depends on which flow you want.  In the first example if you have an exception it wil loop no more

Comment: The best practice is you should surround the statement that has declared to throw a checked exception with try/catch. There is no need to surround everybody else that is not going to throw any checked exception with try/catvh

Comment: It depends. If you think there could be something wrong parsing jsonObject  or processing jsonObject use try catch inside loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you serious you are about the integrity of the data.

- The first example, will run the loop until an exception occurs, and once it does, the catch block is invoked and the loop will no longer run.
- However the second example will enter the try block and try executing the code and if there is an exception, the catch block is invoked and the exception is sorted out. However the loop doesn't end, the next iteration will run right after.

Here is an example. We will consider there is some exception occurring when i = 4

```
try {
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println("" + i);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Output -

```
0
1
2
3
Exception
```

And

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){

    try {
        System.out.println("" + i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

> Output

```
0
1
2
3
Exception
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: nicely explained! Accepted your answer!

Answer (score 2):

**TL,DR: it all boils down to what your purpose is and how you use it.**

---

Suppose, you have a list of Object to be parsed and shown/used, say,

```
[{"name":"Apple"},{"name":"Banana"},{"name":"Mango"}]
```

In case of one data error, if you want, only the correct one's to be used and incorrect one's left out, use **TRY inside the Loop**.

But if you want nothing to be used and just handle the whole exception, use **FOR loop inside the TRY**.

As for example, if you received the following data:

```
[{"name":"Apple"},{"name":"Banana},{"name":"Mango"}] // notice the missing " after Banana
```

In case of **TRY inside the Loop**, it will show only

```
[{"name":"Apple"},{"name":"Mango"}]
```

In case of **FOR loop inside the TRY**, it will show nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the scenario. If there are chances to get exception in any iteration of the loop, then I think try inside the loop is better. Because, after catching exception the loop will continue. But, It the try is out side of the loop, then the loop will break. I'll definitely go for try in the loop as it is more optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your needs actually (also how you use those objects to rest of your code). If you write ***try*** block inside loop, then loop will **continue** all the exceptions. And if you run loop inside ***try*** block, then loop will **break** for **any** exception and will go to your catch block.

When do we write **continue** and when do we write **break** in loop? It depends on our needs, right? That is the case here. Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It may differ according to situation, but I recommended loop inside the for loop, because your code found any exception in 3rd iteration then rest 4th to end iteration will be safe.

Best practice is, try catch should cover only that code which requires.

Answer (score 0):

Its always standard practice to use try catch in code part where exception may occur.There is only one place where exception may occur and its inside the for loop.So,"TRY inside loop" is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already got your answer,  It may differ but i think this practice is good enough :

```
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

        int count = jsonArray.length(); 
        for(int i=0 ; i< count; i++){   
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("jsonObject " + i + ": " + jsonObject);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or you can use , do - catch